# How to merge vector to dataset for each obs

Tags: r

Here is my dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = 1:3, v2 = c('a','b','c'))
df
   v1 v2
1  1  a
2  2  b
3  3  c
```

I have a value vector.

```
abc <- c(10,15,25)
```

How can i have the result like this ?

```
    v1  v2  a   b   c
 1  1   a   10  15  25
 2  2   b   10  15  25
 3  3   c   10  15  25
```

i can't use join to merge them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `replicate` with `cbind`:

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = 1:3, v2 = c('a','b','c'))
abc <- c(10,15,25)
cbind(df, t(replicate(nrow(df), abc)))

  v1 v2  1  2  3
1  1  a 10 15 25
2  2  b 10 15 25
3  3  c 10 15 25
```

### Demo

Edit: As @Ronak pointed out, the following should also work due to recycling rules:

```
cbind(df, t(abc))
```